# How can I control which sound card Ubuntu uses for playback?

Tags: audio, ubuntu-9.04

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 9.04 and Windows XP but am new to Ubuntu. In Windows, I use an M-Audio Audiophile 2496 sound card for recording (because it has RCA input jacks for my mixer), but I don't use it for playback (because my speakers use a 1/8 inch jack); instead, I use the motherboard's built-in sound card.

I tried to recreate this arrangement in Ubuntu, but despite selecting the built-in card for all playback under `System > Preferences > Sound`, I still have inconsistent results. Rhythmbox plays back through the integrated card, but Flash content in the browser and games in the OS send their audio to the Audiophile card.

I have seen recommendations to use a program called "Jack" to control this, but I installed it and found it baffling.

How can I control which card is used for playback, other than disabling one card (as I discovered how to do and explain below)? Also, is there a GUI for disabling hardware, or is it necessary to edit a configuration file?

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't really need the PCI sound card to work when I'm booting Ubuntu, I eliminated the confusion by disabling it. Here's how:

1) I opened Terminal and typed `less /proc/asound/modules` to get a list of the audio drivers being used
2) There were two listed: `snd_hda_intel`, which I recognized as the built-in sound card, and `snd_ice1712`, which I guessed was the Audiophile 2496
3) From terminal, I typed `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to edit the list of drivers that are "blacklisted," meaning they are not loaded at startup. I added these lines to the bottom of the file:

```
#Disable M-Audio Audiophile 2496
blacklist snd_ice1712
```

4) I rebooted. Now the Audiophile card was disabled and all sound came through the built-in card. Success!

Note: I found this solution mainly [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=629391), so thanks to natewiebe13.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses pulseaudio. there is a command to setup the sound "pacmd". You can list all the sources and all the sinks that pulseaudio uses. You can make an script to control it, change the source or the sink ,  and use the  other sound card when you want.